# Issue with Table Join with group by clause

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables Match_Id and Score . Sample Data

Match_Id

```
> ID | HomeTeam  |AwayTeam  
> 1    India      Srilanka
  2    Srilanka   India 
  3    Pakistan   India
```

Score

```
Match_Id  Team    Score
 1        India    1
 1        India    1
 1       Srilanka  1
 3       Pakistan  1
 2        India    1
 1        India    1
```

---

I need to write a query that will give me

```
1  India   (3) Srilanka (1)
2 Srilanka (0) India  (1)
3 Pakistan (1) India  (0)
```

Thank you !

Comment: Have you tried to write it yourself? And I think the values in your second table are incorrect..

Comment: I dont understand the result you want to get. try to add what you have tried

Comment: yes.I have and its an example ..but thats the data I have ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select m.ID
  , m.HomeTeam
  , HomeTeamScore = sum(case when m.HomeTeam = s.Team then 1 else 0 end)
  , m.AwayTeam
  , AwayTeamScore = sum(case when m.AwayTeam = s.Team then 1 else 0 end)
from Match_id m
  inner join Score s on m.ID = s.Match_Id
group by m.ID
  , m.HomeTeam
  , m.AwayTeam
order by m.ID
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b38b7/3).